# See commands of "Print Test Page"?

Tags: windows, printing

I am working on an Argox printer using PPLB command set. What I need is to see the commands sent to the printer when I click "Print Test Page" button of the printer properties panel. Saving to a .prn file would be perfect. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If the printer is connected via network (not cable), you can trace the transmitted packets. However, decoding them would require some knowledge of the protocol.

Comment: It is connected by usb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Printer Properties (not Printing Preferences) and go to the Ports tab.

   [image: Screenshot of Ports tab of Printer Properties dialog]
2. Note down the default output port.
3. Select the `FILE:` output port.
4. Click Apply (or OK).
5. When you print, you should get a "Save Print Output As" dialog. This will allow you to save as a `.prn` file. This should work with the "Print Test Page" button (that's where I got the screenshot).

   [image: Screenshot of Save Print Output As dialog]
6. Don't forget to change your Port back to the original setting so you can print again!

Answer (score 3):

You can **pause** the printer and **spool** the document, to [capture the spool file](https://typehaus.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207444723-How-do-I-capture-a-spool-file-from-a-Windows-print-queue-) in `C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS`, or you can just select the option to `Keep printed documents`in **Printer Properties** (remember to uncheck it when you're done testing).

Comment: +1 for keeping printed documents. Just don't forget to uncheck it when you're done testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wireshark to look at the USB packets being sent to the printer.

https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB

Comment: Better read the comments before answering : "It is connected by usb".

Comment: @harrymc, Wireshark can capture from USB, so what is the problem?

Comment: Only for USB attached network interfaces. The printer isn't a network adapter.